# Finding the index of multiple index of the max values in intervals in a vector from "scratch" in R?

Tags: r

```
max_value_idx
[1] 4 6 7
```

I would like to know the indexes of max in every interval of 10 and if there 2 elements that are max, I would like to add them into the max_value_index

```
vect_1 =c(2,3,5,10,1,9,4,7,6,8,21,13,51,14,11,91,91,17,16,28) 
no_of_intervals_of_10 = (length(vect_1))/10
max_value_idx = c()

new_max = 0
for (n in  1:no_of_intervals_of_10)
{
  max_value = -Inf
  
  # for each interval
  for (s in 1:10)
  {
    i = (n-1)*10+s
    if (vect_1[i] >= max_value)
    {
      if (vect_1[i] > max_value)
      {max_value = vect_1[i]
      max_value_idx = c(max_value_idx, s)
      new_max = max_value}
      
      else if (vect_1[i] == new_max)
      {
        max_value_idx = c(max_value_idx, s)
      }
    }
    
  }
}

max_value_idx
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 3 6 7
```

However, I couldn't get the desired output with the code.

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

just by using basic operators/loops without using the operator %in% or any functions in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following.

```
f <- \(v, n=10) {
  s <- length(v)/n
  stopifnot(s %% 1 == 0)  ## check if length is divisible by n
  unlist(sapply(1:s, \(x) {
    r <- v[(1:n) + n*(x - 1L)] == max(v[(1:n) + n*(x - 1L)])
    ind <- integer(sum(r))
    j <- 1L
    for (i in seq_along(r)) {
      if (r[i]) {
        ind[j] <- i
        j <- j + 1L
      }
    }
    ind
  }))
}

f(vect_1)
# [1] 4 6 7
```